# ContentScale.FillWidth is not working Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to make a Composable which I can ruse by passing image of any size to fill its Width by using

```
compose_version = 1.0.0-beta07
```

```
@Composable 
fun image(image:Int){
          Image(painter = painterResource(image), 
          contentDescriptionn = null, contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
}
```

When I am passing other images it's working but when I am passing a image which width and height are same it's not working

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing size related modifier, like `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`, `Modifier.width(100.dp)`, `Modifier.size(24.dp)`, depending on your need. If square image is required then add `Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)`.

```
@Composable
fun Image(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, @DrawableRes image: Int){
    Image(
        modifier = modifier,
        painter = painterResource(image),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
}

Image(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), image = R.drawable.sq1)
```

If image always needs to fill full available width then

```
@Composable
fun Image(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, @DrawableRes image: Int){
    Image(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        painter = painterResource(image),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
}

Image(image = R.drawable.sq1)
```

---

**Update: Clarification for rectangular images**

```
@Composable
fun Image(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, @DrawableRes image: Int){
    Image(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(1f),
        painter = painterResource(image),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
}
```

For a given available width, the height of the Image composable will be calculated using aspect ratio. So image composable will be square with the maximum width possible.

Now comes the scaling to place the image inside this square composable. Here `ContentScale.FillWidth` will be used to determine position and scaling of image.

For **portrait** images, the image will fill full width of the square and will be centered vertically cropping out some upper and lower parts of the image.

For **landscape** images, again due to `ContentScale.FillWidth` scaling, the full width of the square will be filled by image but since the height of the image isn't sufficient so the image will be centered vertically, leaving blank space in the upper and lower part of the square.

Comment: if I add aspectRatio(1f) it will affect rectangle images??

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify the rectangular image scenario.

Comment: Thanks dude 

Comment: aspect ratio saved my day :D Thanks a lot.