# Image composable not taking the specified room in view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have the following composable but the image does not take the full width of the column? then I would like the image to scale so it fits the whole width of the image in the view then adjust the height so it keeps its aspect ratio which is why I have fillWidth. What am I doing wrong?

```
 @ExperimentalCoilApi

@Composable
fun Screen1() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize() ,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            painter = rememberImagePainter(""),
            contentDescription = "",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )

        Text(
            text = "sample text",
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold)
        )

        Text(
            text = "sample text" ,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
            maxLines = 2,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 12.sp)

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: use `ContentScale.FillBounds`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781972/contentscale-fillwidth-is-not-working-jetpack-compose turns out I was missing .aspectRatio(1f) basically it was drawing the image but it had no height so it looked like it was not being displayed.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: I fixed it by doing what I said on my last comment, did you figure yours out? @dazza5000

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code. It works fine. You don't need to use the aspectRatio modifier. I suspect that maybe you are using an outdated version of Compose and/or Coil.

I tested this with Compose 1.1.0-beta03

Comment: I am using compose 1.0.4 can't go higher due to some restrictions. and I am using the following coil dependency:     implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.1")
no accompanist, what is the difference between coil-compose and coil and what are you using accompanist for in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with the accompanist version of coil. But I replaced it with the "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0" and it still works. I also tried it with Compose 1.0.4 and it works. No need for the use of the aspectRatio. You must have some other issues.

Comment: I recreated this sample and is not my actual code, it might be that something else is causing this higher in the hierarchy